Not able to kill thread
I am executing parallel workflow actions(Any one task as one action) via windows service created using .NET 4.5 C# and QUARTZ 2.3.3.When end user pause workflow execution then trying to kill that current running workflow using Quartz Interrupt method which has below implementation but thread not killing.Even not getting any exception.Simply Interrupt fails here.
 private void KillTheThread()
 {
     try
     {
         _logger.Info(" Error : Thread is going to Abort"+ _currentThread.ManagedThreadId + " at:"+DateTime.Now);

         if(_CancellationTokenSource != null)
         {
             _CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
         }

         _currentThread.Abort();
        
         Thread.Sleep(500);

         _logger.Info(" Error : Workflow  is aborted:"+ _workflowName+" at:"+DateTime.Now);
          _logger.Info(" Error : Thread current state is "+ _currentThread.ThreadState.ToString()+" at:"+DateTime.Now);
         _currentThread = null;

         return;
     }
     catch (ThreadAbortException exc)
     {
         if (exc.InnerException!=null)
             _logger.Info(" ************Error : InnerException occured in KillTheThread: " + exc.InnerException);
         else
             _logger.Info(" ************Error : Exception occured in KillTheThread: " + exc.Message);
     }
    
 }

I tried to reattempt killing thread for minimum 3 times but still no success.
Any help/clue will be appreciated....

See Whats wrong with thread abort. So .Abort() is the wrong approach. But it is not clear to me if you can use cooperative cancellation, or what the overall goal is.

Goal is to kill thread once user pause workflow but thread not killing.I tried printing thread state and its in "WaitSleepJoin " and after some time its in "Aborted" but still workflow execution goes on.

If the thread runs code that you control you should post the code that the thread is running. If this is third party code you need call the code in a separate application. Since processes can be cleanly shut down, but the same is not true for threads.

My thread basically executing workflow actions based on user inputs and updating status in DB.Code is heavy with many lines so not possible to share here.My only concern is why thread not getting deleted once its Interrupted.

My thread basically executing workflows(multiple tasks as actions) based on user inputs configured and updating status in DB.Code is heavy with many lines so not possible to share here.My only concern is once user pause running workflow(for me its Quartz Job), its get interrupted and then it must get deleted which is not happening.
